# Dependency injected UserManager causes concurrency issue: How to make UserManager use different DbContext?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

In my Blazor server side app with EF Core and MS Identity, I ran into a *A second operation was started on this context instance before a previous operation completed* error. I could trace it to MS Identity `UserManager`, who seems to use the same `DbContext` for all Blazor components.

My parent component and some child components use `UserManager`. Since - according to my understanding - each component runs in a separte thread, each component should use a different `DbContext` to prevent such concurrency issues.

I use dependency injection to obtain the `UserManager` in each component, and unfortunately, I do not know who to check which `DbContext` is used by `UserManager`, but the hash code of `UserManager` in each component instance is the same, strongly indicating that multiple Blazor components share the same `DbContext`, which causes the concurrency issue.

As a workaround and as a test if my conclusions are correct, I use a `SemaphoreSlim` to synchronize the use of `UserManager` across the differnt Blazor components and the concurrency issue goes away. So I am confident that the injected `UserManager`s share a single `DbContext`.

I register a 'fresh' instance of the `DbContext` for MS Identity using the factory accoring to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64185721/645282)

```
services.AddTransient<myContext>(p => p.GetRequiredService<IDbContextFactory<myContext>>().CreateDbContext());
```

and here I expect the problem: MS Identity only gets, respectively uses, a `DbContext` and not a `DbContextFactory`, so it has to use the same `DbContext` when injecting a `UserManager`.

Is there a way to make `UserManager` use a 'fresh' `DbContext` each time it is injected?

Comment: I filed this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/43687) but it was closed without a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found something that might help. I was experiencing this issue while trying to inject the usermanager to get user roles for a user table. I found [this](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/18340#issuecomment-574638552) post. I used the inherit component base then Service.GetUserRolesAsync(user)

I was able to loop through the user manager and get all the roles without causing a concurrency exception.

here is a copy of the contents of the post.

```
@page "/"
@inherits OwningComponentBase<UserManager<IdentityUser>>
<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

number of users: @Users.Count()
<button @onclick="@(async () => await Add())">click me. I work if you use Sqlite</button>

<ul>
@foreach(var user in Users) 
{
    <li>@user.UserName</li>
}
</ul>

@code {
    IQueryable<IdentityUser> Users;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Users = Service.Users;
    }

    public async Task Add()
    {
        await Service.CreateAsync(new IdentityUser { UserName = $"test_{Guid.NewGuid().ToString()}" });
    }
}
```

Edit: My answer may be flawed. But [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-7.0#utility-base-component-classes-to-manage-a-di-scope) is some more documentation.