# Blazor Server + EF Core 7 + Idenitty --> using a custom DbContext and DbContextFactory

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side, asp.net-core-identity, ef-core-7.0

The question is simple: how can I make my own context using the identity. I don't want to use the default ApplicationDbContext.

In Program.cs by default you have:

```cs
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
```

When I change that to use

```cs
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection") ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Connection string 'DefaultConnection' not found.");
void BuildOptions(DbContextOptionsBuilder options) => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString).EnableSensitiveDataLogging(); // todo: not for production

builder.Services.AddDbContext<OpmContext>(BuildOptions);
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<OpmContext>(BuildOptions);

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<OpmContext>();
```

and change my own DbContext to inherit from IdentityContext:

```cs
public class OpmContext : IdentityDbContext 
{
    public OpmContext(DbContextOptions<OpmContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

I get:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.IDbContextFactory`1[Foo.Bar.Data.OpmContext] Lifetime: Singleton

I had a look at [Using Identity with AddDbContextFactory in Blazor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64169025/using-identity-with-adddbcontextfactory-in-blazor) but can't seem to get it working. Any suggestions?

The goal is to inject and use `IDbContextFactory<OpmContext> DbFactory` in razor pages or own services.

Comment: Your issue seems like this one [Use both AddDbContextFactory() and AddDbContext() extension methods in the same project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65022729/use-both-adddbcontextfactory-and-adddbcontext-extension-methods-in-the-same). 
Try to remove the AddDbContext. If you really need one register it as singleton.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order:

```
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<OpmContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

builder.Services
    .AddDbContext<OpmContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<OpmContext>();
```